# How to include a tree view in drop down in kendo angular UI

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

I need a dropdown tree in kendo angular UI, it should look like,

[image: Screen Shot]

This control is available in kendo UI for Jquery, but not in kendo angular.
How to customise it, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the same control is not (yet) available for Angular. You can combine [Popup](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/popup/) and [Treeview](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/) and build something similar.

Here's a simple example in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpfyck?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts